# Logrotate - how change it so that it never deletes logs and will create a .gz every 6 months?

Tags: nginx, logrotate

I read the ***man logrotate***, but it's still unclear to me. My questions are mainly related to the NGINX webserver logs.

This is my current logrotate.conf:

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

and in /etc/logrotate.d I have among the others also: nginx:

```
/var/log/nginx/*log {
    create 0644 nginx nginx
    daily
    rotate 10
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -USR1 `cat /run/nginx.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

And these are some of the .gz I can see:

```
access.log-20150430.gz
access.log-20150509.gz (created after ~10 days)
access.log-20150524.gz (created after ~15 days)
access.log-20150528.gz (created after ~4 days)
```

1. Why the .gz logs are created so often and at so "random" timeframes?
2. What should I change in order to have new .gz created every 6 months and/or after a .log file will be bigger than 100MB?
3. With **rotate 10** does it mean that if I have already 10 .gz files, then when it compresses the 11th, it will automatically delete the oldest .gz file? If yes, how can I avoid deleting logfiles? I must keep them all, even if very old.
4. What is the difference between **daily** and **rotate 10**?
5. Is the create permission for those files ok?
6. After I change something on the logrotate.conf, should I restart some service, or the changes should be applied immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think logrotate manual is clear about most of your points. Here are my answers:

1. Using `daily` causes log rotation to happen every day. So, you need to check why it is not happening on daily basis. For example, this can be caused by the other option `notifempty` if the log file was empty for few days.
2. I can't find an option to do it every 6 months, but you have `monthly` and `yearly`. For the size confitions, you can use `size 100M`.
3. Yes. To keep them all, you can choose a very large value.
4. `daily` specifies how often to rotate while `rotate` specifies number of log files kept.
5. If the log does not contain sensitive information (others can read), it should be fine.
6. No, you don't need to restart anything.